# Unable to make enemy move towards player

Tags: python, pygame

I'm struggling to get this working. Basically, I want my enemy sprite to chase my player sprite. At the moment, it moves away diagonally to the bottom right edge of the screen.

I'm learning python my making a game and am still new so I apologise if this is a very simple thing I'm having issues with.

Relevant code:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.bitmap = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
        self.enemy_rect = self.bitmap.get_rect()
        self.enemy_rect.topleft = [100, 200]
        self.speed = 2

    def move_to_player(self, Player):
        dx, dy = self.enemy_rect.x - player.player_rect.x, self.enemy_rect.y - player.player_rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist == 0:
            dist = 1
        else:
            dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist

        self.enemy_rect.x += dx * self.speed
        self.enemy_rect.y += dx * self.speed

while 1:  # main game loop
enemy.move_to_player(player)
```

And all code, for context:

```
import pygame
import sys
import pygame.locals
import math

pygame.init() 

size = width, height = 800, 500
colour = 100, 20, 30  # colour for background

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.bitmap = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
        self.player_rect = self.bitmap.get_rect(
        self.player_rect.topleft = [100, 200]

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.player_rect.centerx += x
        self.player_rect.centery += y

    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.shipRect))

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.bitmap = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
        self.enemy_rect = self.bitmap.get_rect()
        self.enemy_rect.topleft = [100, 200]
        self.speed = 2

    def move_to_player(self, Player):
        dx, dy = self.enemy_rect.x - player.player_rect.x, self.enemy_rect.y - player.player_rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist == 0:
            dist = 1
        else:
            dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist

        self.enemy_rect.x += dx * self.speed
        self.enemy_rect.y += dx * self.speed

player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()

player.player_rect.x = 50
player.player_rect.y = 50

enemy.enemy_rect.x = 500
enemy.enemy_rect.y = 300

while 1:  # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.move(0, 5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.move(0, -5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move(-5, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move(5, 0)

        if player.player_rect.colliderect(enemy.enemy_rect):
            pygame.display.set_caption('Hit!')

    screen.fill(colour)
    screen.blit(player.bitmap, player.player_rect)
    screen.blit(enemy.bitmap, enemy.enemy_rect)
    enemy.move_to_player(player)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `self.enemy_rect.y += dx * self.speed` probably should be `self.enemy_rect.y += dy * self.speed`

Secondly, I think you have your math backwards such that your enemy will flee.  Let's try a simple example:

```
Player at 0,0; enemy at 2,0.  
Expected result if speed = 2: both at 0,0
dx = 2, dy = 0 (before normalizing by hypot)
dx = 1, dy = 0 (after)
New result: player still at 0,0; enemy at 4,0
```

Comment: Aha, thank you! My maths was backwards, yeah. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Here this is what I use for this...

```
if PlayerX > AI_X:
    AI_X += 3
if PlayerX < AI_X:
    AI_X -= 3
if PlayerY > AI_Y:
    AI_Y += 3
if PlayerY < AI_Y:
    AI_Y -= 3
```

Hope this helps!